# elementary OS Loki: I have to put the laptop to sleep right after booting to make it work

Tags: release-loki, boot, suspend

In the last week or so I started having problems with Loki while booting. The laptop (Lenovo Z50-70) boots to the desktop, but only the background image is shown, without the dock or the top panel (I tried starting the terminal with winkey + T, but to no awail). I have to put the computer to sleep by pressing the power button, and then wake it up in order to make everything work properly. Anyone know a solution to that?

Also, sometimes the laptop doesn't wake up from sleep (it just shows a black screen), so it has to be shut down and booted up again.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I use the same laptop and sometimes I have that problem too.

In case of only background image displayed I click **Ctrl+Alt+F1** and then **Ctrl+Alt+F7**. So that I switch to cli and then to gui.

In case of black screen after wake up. It brings the system after a while or you just need to reboot manually. :/

But for a month or so I haven't meet this problem, I thought that they fixed that in some update.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input :) 

I thought that I'd get an e-mail when someone comments (new to stackexchange).

Anyway, I figured out that pressing alt+F1 manages to solve the problem, but I've encountered it only once or twice since the post. 

Hope this info helps someone.